# Python3 : Uiautomator wrapper for Android testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, android-uiautomator

I've been trying to use Python Module for Uiautomator, but there seems to be an issue. I've imported it through

- pip install atx-uitomator

and use the following to import the classes

- from uiautomator import device as d

When I do d.info() or d.screen.on(), the device doesn't seem to respond and is throwing the following error:

- A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

This error is when a keyboard interrupt happens and when I run the same from a script it throws an "device import error."

I'm unable to figure out the issue and seem to hit a dead end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name 'Device' , when using uiautomator Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421590/importerror-cannot-import-name-device-when-using-uiautomator-python-3)

Comment: @Matt B yes it is! couldn't get an answer there, can you help ?